# How can I pass one process to another using pipe (read file contents-get contents-create new file)?

Tags: python, file, process, subprocess, pipe

as in the question, I would like to pass process A, that is the code below which reads the contents of the outfile.txt file, to be passed to process B which will "download" the contents of process A and create a new file with the contents of process A?

How can I do this or can someone give me an idea?

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['python','outfile.txt'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
  line = proc.stdout.readline()
  if not line:
    break
  print("test:", line.rstrip())
```

Comment: What do you mean by the contents of a process?

Comment: I don't understand what you try to do. You can pass only data/string, not process. If you want to run two `subprocess` then run it in then same code and use `stdout` from first process with `stdin` in other process - and this way you can send data/string from one process to another..

Comment: shouldn't be simpler to run `open('outfile.txt').read()` ? OR `for line in open('outfile.txt'): print('test:', line.rstrip())` Eventually with `sys.stdout.write` instead of `print()`

Comment: do you get erorr message? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas I just want Process A (which is the code above) and B to communicate over a Pipe. Process A reads the file line by line and sends them to process B, which then writes them to another file.

Comment: @Barmar I mean that the activity in the first process should be transferred to another process that will make copies to the new file. (I explained more precisely in the comment above)

Comment: as I wrote in previous commend:  run two `subprocess` in then same code and use `stdout` from first process with `stdin` in other process. if you want to send without changes then it could even use `process2 = Popen(... stdin=process1.stdout)` withoute any `while`-loop. And it should work like in shell `script1 | script2`

Comment: BTW: is your code work ? As for me it is missing script name - `["python", "script.py", "outfile.txt"]` and this script should read data from `outfile.txt` and display it with `print()` or `sys.stdout.write()` and then your code may get lines from `stdout` As for me all this is overcomplicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand what you want to do.

For me `Process A` and `Process B` means two `Popen` in one script.

if you want to send directly from one process to another then you can use

```
process_B = subprocess.Popen(..., stdin=process_A.stdout)
```

---

Minimal working code. It runs `ls | sort -r` on Linux

```
import subprocess
#import sys

process_A = subprocess.Popen(['ls'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process_B = subprocess.Popen(['sort', '-r'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=process_A.stdout)

# - show result - 

for line in process_B.stdout:
    #sys.stdout.write(line.decode())
    print(line.decode().rstrip())
```

or show result with `communicate()

```
import subprocess

process_A = subprocess.Popen(['ls'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process_B = subprocess.Popen(['sort', '-r'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=process_A.stdout)

# - show result - 

stout, stderr = process_B.communicate()
print(stout.decode())
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to modify data between processes

```
import subprocess

process_A = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '/'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process_B = subprocess.Popen(['sort', '-r'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

# - get all from one process -

stdout_A, stderr_A = process_A.communicate()
    
# - modify all -
 
stdout_A = stdout_A.upper()

# - send all to other process and get result -

stout_B, stderr_B = process_B.communicate(stdout_A)
print(stout_B.decode())
```

or

```
import subprocess

process_A = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '/'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process_B = subprocess.Popen(['sort', '-r'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

# - send from one process to another line by line - 

for line in process_A.stdout:
    line = line.upper() 
    process_B.stdin.write(line)

# - get result -

stout_B, stderr_B = process_B.communicate()
print(stout_B.decode())
```